# Neverwinter Modules

Tags: neverwinter

I have been playing Never-winter for ages now but still don't have a clue how the modules work...Do i need to download them or are they part of the patches or how do I get them and what are the changes in each of them? can someone please explain to me exactly how they work and how to get them?

Comment: I think they're just called modules to match pen & paper terminology and, interestingly, matching pen and paper modules from WotC. From what I can tell, they're just your standard large updates (maybe a version increment, maybe an "expansion" -- whatever you want to call it). Historically, they seem to have introduced the various campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

Way late to the party, but Modules are included in the patches.  The content is available to go after you log in after a patch - usually by means of a quest and it's 100% free, though they tend to have a "pack" that's released with them that you can buy, ~$25-35 for a small pack, $60 if it's got a mount.